# Do I need to install the Raspbian image BEFORE RetroPie?

Tags: raspbian, retropie

I've just purchased a Raspberry Pi B+ and I want to use it as a little emulation station of sorts.

I don't want to be hand held through the set-up but I'd just like to know whether or not I need to install the original Raspbian image before I install RetroPie or if I can just install RetroPie from a formatted card?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Petroblock](http://blog.petrockblock.com/retropie/#retroimage): "The RetroPie SD-card image is a ready-to-use image that provides a full installation of all systems and functions that are supported by the RetroPie Setup Script."

So I take it, that one just installs this image to the SD card and that is it.