# Retropie 3.2" tft screen not working

Tags: retropie

I am working on a little project but ran into some trouble and cant figure out how to fix it.
I recently bought a waveshare 3.2" screen from ebay and it works, but not the way I want it to.
I am making a portable raspberry pi with the OS retropie.
But the problem is,
When I start up the raspberry, it shows me the OS's menu on hdmi, but not on the tft screen. On the tft it only shows the desktop of raspbian, the OS retropie is based on.
So basicaly what I want is that I can force the HDMI through the TFT, is this possible?
Any other suggestions?
Pls help

Comment: What do you mean by the OS menu? The OS Retropie's so called "raspi-config" or the so called "start menu"?

Comment: I dont mean the raspi config menu, I mean the actual OS, what you get when it starts up

Comment: So, it is loading different OS to the different screens? What do you mean different OS's. See answer below for some ideas though.

Comment: Retropie is a OS which runs on Raspbian. Like 2 OS's in one. But if you start the raspberry up it will just inmidiatly launch retropie asplashscreen. This is how I want it to be. But on the tft it doesnt launch the retropie asplashscreen, it launches the raspbian desktop.

Comment: Ok...great! Then see my answer below for some help hopefully. :-)

Comment: I'll try, thanx btw!

Comment: It seems this doesnt work :(
When I want to turn the tft on I use these commands in the terminal:
sudo modprobe fbtft_device name=waveshare
sudo modprobe spi-bcm2708
FRAMEBUFFER=/dev/fb1 startx

The last command turns my tft on and it shows the Raspbian desktop,
My hdmi screen turns black...

Comment: And how can I edit the config.txt? I didnt try to change the things you said yet so maybe that will do it

Comment: To edit config.txt go into the boot folder on your pi or plug the card into a windows pc and and it is there!

Comment: Still no luck,
My hdmi screen now says that it cant support the current resolution,
And my 3.2 inch screen still shows me the raspbian desktop :(
There is a command in retropie called "emulationstation"
If you  type that in it will start up the emulation station menu (asplashscreen) But when I try this on my screen it says that I need to shut down the X server first, and when I do so, my 3.2 inch screen turns black...

Comment: Before, doing the config changes could you try the do_start() function edit shown below? I think that might fix it. You could work around this problem possibly by making a script that auto-starts the emulationstation on boot. It would be a bash file and then you would put a cron entry. Then you would have to disable the x server. Be carefull though. Best have a backup before you start changing things like this! Or if emulation station is a windows manager you could set that to be the default in preferences.

Comment: I dont know if I did it right, it looks something like this:

[line1 ]start()   [line2]/usr/local/bin/fbcp &

Comment: That looks right...did you reboot yet?  Also, see the link for more information.

Comment: I did but the same thing happened, only it doesnt show anything anymore on the hdmi, it only says: "resolution not supported"

Comment: According to adafruit,"Though the Pi has no trouble generating 320x240 video, not all HDMI monitors can display this. You might see “no signal” on the monitor following the next reboot. That’s okay…with everything set up right, it’ll all be routed to the PiTFT."

Comment: Make sure you wait a minute for the touchscreen, it should take a second to load the emulation station. The adafruit sight has a lot of configs I haven't mentioned. I suggest you go through it systematically and see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: See http://forums.adafruit.com/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=58665 and the links given in forum there...that might be a way to fix it.

Comment: Hey, im trying the adafruit guide right now, but I have a little problem.
At a certain time I need to use this command:
sudo adafruit-pitft-helper -t [display type]
I have an 3.2 inch screen, but the console says the only type I could use are 2.8 inch, 3.5 inch or 2.2 inch

Comment: Well...that would be a problem. Did you try to do it anyway?

Comment: That possibly could be your issue; hopefully not but it could be that the driver does not support your resolution.

Comment: However, you might have success trying to follow directions in the link I posted in the comments. A person on the adafruit forum there had your same issue though with a 2.8'er. I think you should give it a shot though.

Comment: I did, but the screen stays white
Still no progress

Comment: We're really out on a limb here, if what I have said does not work, I honestly don't know what else you can do.  I'm still looking though.;-)

Comment: No problem! Hope we can find a solution!

Comment: I found another little package in the box the tft screen came with it it is a little cd, I opened it and it includes an img file for the screen. Also some kind of manual. However, I dont know if this will help me with the OS i am using right now

Comment: That will most likely be a hacked version of Raspbian to work with your screen. I had the same kind of thing. You'll have to write it the the micro-sd card. I am not sure how retro-pie works but if you install it over Raspbian you might could get it to work since the image is specific to your screen! Let me know the results!

Comment: I don't mean hacked in a bad way, by the way. But sometimes it can be annoying not knowing what customization has been done. My problem was http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/32011/disabling-auto-login-when-normal-ways-dont-work/32040?noredirect=1#comment40818_32040

Comment: I am a beginner at raspberry pi (15 years old),
so could you explain to me how I can write Retropie over Raspbian?

Comment: I assume via the retropie setup script as shown here:http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/14824/i-want-raspbian-and-retropie-how-do-i-get-both

Comment: Also, thinking about this...do you really wan't Raspbian and retropie. According to this link: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/23257/do-i-need-to-install-the-raspbian-image-before-retropie?rq=1 you can write it to the sd card and you are good to go. I don't know what kind of touch screen you have but you would probably have to edit files like I presume you did with your current setup in order to get it to send the screen data to the gpio.

Comment: Hi, i've found a workaround! Its working now! I installed the hacked raspbian version on the raspberry and it works, and from the pistore I downloaded a ps1 and gba emulator! Thanks for all the help. So happy right now :D

Comment: Great glad to see this come to completion! If you still want retropie though I believe you can install it using the script mentioned above on the hacked version.Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem you want to get to raspi-config. Open a LX-Terminal and type `sudo raspi-config`. This will bring you to the configuration menu. Otherwise, see below.

If you are talking about the "asplashscreen" try this. Navigate here:`sudo nano /etc/init.d/asplashscreen` and look for the `do_start()` function. Then insert as the first line in the function: `/usr/local/bin/fbcp &`.

Possibly, you could change these to fix your problem in config.txt.

```
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
hdmi_cvt=320 240 60 1 0 0 0
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=87
dtoverlay=pitft28r,rotate=90,speed=80000000,fps=60
```

For more configuration that might help and more explanation, see this [post by Adafruit](https://learn.adafruit.com/running-opengl-based-games-and-emulators-on-adafruit-pitft-displays/pitft-setup) about Retropie and touchscreens. Hope that helps!