# Disabling Auto-Login when normal ways don't work

Tags: software-installation, software-compatibility

I am running a custom version of Raspbian on my B+ with a touchscreen. This OS was customized to work with the WaveShare SpotPear A screen they sell. It is configured to auto login to to the desktop as the pi user. I wan't to disable that so I tried the following:

- `sudo raspi-config`; boot to console option
- Commented out all autologin lines in lightdm.conf
- Went to /etc/inittab and verified there were no incorrect Entries doing the opposite of this [tutorial](http://elinux.org/RPi_Debian_Auto_Login).
- Tried to disable lightdm with the command `Sudo update-rc.d lightdm disable 2` giving me this error:

  `update-rc.d: using dependency based boot sequencing
  insserv: warning: current start runlevel (s) (3 4 5) of script lightdm 'overrides LSB defaults (2 3 4 5).
  insserv: warning: current stop runlevel (s) (0 1 2 6) of script lightdm 'overrides LSB defaults (0 1 6).`
- Tried `sudo apt-get --purge lightdm` gave an error saying stuff depended on it. But things that depended on it could not be uninstalled because it said they already were. So I used aptitude and was able to fix that and finally uninstalled it and rebooted. It brought me back to the desktop again! I checked in the lightdm folder and there wasn't a lightdm.conf file anymore. Just to see what happened I logged off. Which does not show screen but shows the terminal. I proceded to login as pi and type startx. It then showed a message like it had worked talking about who created it etc but did not go to desktop or let me type anything. Ctrl + Alt + Backspace is the only thing that saved me! I then rebooted and it went to the desktop like nothing happened.

Other questions have addressed this question but the answers above worked. I haven't had success with any of these. Does anyone know further configuration possibilities that could fix this issue?

Comment: Much better +1 is the source of the kernel online if so you could look through t for the changes. second is the screen using lightdm? this may be one of the changes they made. Also, have you contacted the seller? This thread may help https://github.com/notro/fbtft/issues/215

Comment: I found the answer...by mistake! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer by mistake when I was getting a bash file to run at boot!

## Solution

To fix this problem:

- nagivate to `/etc/rc.local`.
- In the file, right before exit(0), remove the line containing `su -1 pi -c startx` where pi is the username being logged in.

The line will most likely have extra commands in it so don't be surprised if it looks a little different.  As a precaution it might be best to comment it out and reboot to make sure it works for you instead of deleting the line all together!

Comment: Wow -- please tell me the SpotPear people did not really put `sudo` in `rc.local`.  It runs root...

Comment: My bad...it actually starts with su...fixed it.